# How to get email from facebook in cordova application?

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

i want to get email after login with my cordova application

but when i added a permission with Graph API Explorer , i found this

message 
[image]

yes i added permission :

[image]

in my controller :

```
.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.facebook("app-id", ["email", "user_birthday","user_website", "user_location", "user_relationships"]).then(function(result) {
            $localStorage.accessToken = result.access_token;});




.controller("ProfileController", function($scope, $http, $localStorage, $location) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
            $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", { params: { access_token: $localStorage.accessToken, fields: "id,email,name,gender,email,location,website,picture,relationship_status", format: "json" }}).then(function(result) {
                $scope.profileData = result.data;

             //alert(JSON.stringify(result.data));

            }, function(error) {
                //alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
                console.log(error);
            });
```

i found this result :

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: Did you add permissions?

Comment: yes i added permission ,look please i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users don't need an email to use Facebook afaik, and it may not be confirmed yet. The debug message is very clear about that. There is no guarantee to always get the Email, even with the `email` permission.

Just to make sure, test this API call: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail&version=v2.5

Comment: in my application cordova ,i want when a user is login with facebook i get her email and saved after in my DB

Comment: i know what you want to achieve, that´s not the point. read my answer again. you just can´t always get the email, the debug message is very clear.

Comment: ok in my controller i added scope from email but i don't get it ,look please i edit my question

Comment: i know that too, you really need to understand my answer, and the debug message. you can´t get the email if it is not available or not confirmed. you even added it to the fields, so that would be the only explanation. and again, the debug message is very clear, not sure what to add.

Comment: please my email is available

Comment: there are 3 reasons why you would not get an email: not in the scope parameter, not in the fields parameter, and the reason from the debug message. make sure your email is REALLY confirmed and available.